# How to post images to facebook via windows phone?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

In my application image has to post to Facebook,mail.Sorry i am new to windows phone.i don't have a idea.please help me.what i can do first.

Comment: you better start reading tutorials first then share what you have done, I am sure you will get replies for your questions quicker in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share a status you can use your facebook account on your phone using Share link task (with this method you can only post on your wall) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

To post (pictures, messages or others) on every wall you have access you need some things :

First you need to create a facebook application using this link : 
[Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/)

After that you need to identify yourself using a WebBrowser control with the link related to your application. The application requests authorization to perform certain actions such as posting. You need to detail the authorizations like this :

```
Dictionary<string, string> uriParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        {"client_id", "your app id"},
                        {"response_type", "token"},
                        {"scope", "user_about_me, offline_access, publish_stream"}, //The rights
                        {"redirect_uri", "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"}, 
                        {"display", "touch"}
                    };
```

The Dictionary also contains the redirection uri to define if the operation was successful.

Finally you are authentified and receive an access token. Now you can use a WebRequest POST to post a message using this token :

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/" + the id of your wall + "/feed");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream((reqResult) =>
            {
                using (Stream strm = request.EndGetRequestStream(reqResult))
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strm))
                {
                    writer.Write(client.AccessToken);
                    writer.Write("&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(status));
                }
                request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                        using (var rstrm = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookPostResponse));
                            var postResponse = serializer.ReadObject(rstrm) as FacebookPostResponse;
                            callback(true, null);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        callback(false, ex);
                    }
                }, null);
            }, null);
```

Here is how to post a message on a facebook page,

Comment: After that you can use the same principle to post a picture. On the first link you will be able to find how to post pictures

Answer (score 1):

You should give the Facebook C# SDK a try

[Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/)

I have built this in once in an app of mine. They have plenty examples available which should be useful.